# NoMethodError: undefined method `pluck' for #<Model>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am trying to fetch the email id from my **User** model by joining it with another model called **Equipment**. The association between two models is as follows:

```
class Equipment
  belongs_to :user
end

class User
  has_many :equipments
end
```

The **Equipment** has a column named `identifier`
So at first I tried fetching the email of a user as follows.

```
 @email = Equipment.joins(:user).where(identifier: "LID-0000061").pluck(:email)
```

This worked and gave me the email of the user who added that equipment.

Now I am trying to fetch the `email` of **last** added equipment by doing following:

```
@email = Equipment.joins(:user).last.pluck(:email)
```

I got:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `pluck' for #<Equipment>
```

My best guess is that I am doing it wrong. Can somebody please tell how do I pluck the email of that last equipment?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

the `pluck` method works for the `ActiveRecord::Relation`, not the model itself. when you add the `last` method, it returns a model instance, so directly visit it's column, no need to use `pluck`

try this:

```
@email = Equipment.joins(:user).last.user.email
```

or

```
@email = Equipment.joins(:user).pluck(:email).last
```

Comment: NoMethodError: undefined method `email` for #<Equipment>

Comment: em, try `@email = Equipment.joins(:user).last.user.email`

Comment: and actually you can also choose `@email = Equipment.joins(:user).pluck(:email).last`.

Comment: what if you need to pluck more than one column though?

Answer (score 0):

**Pluck** works with **ActiveRecord::Relation** not with model instance.You can use select too, instead of pluck.

```
If you want to use pluck, you can follow like this:

@email = Equipment.joins(:user).pluck(:email).last
```